# Can I use a General Public License code from a github repositiry?

Tags: gpl, license

I'm working on PDF password cracking tool which borrows a file from [John_the_ripper_bleeding_jumbo](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper). I want only one single file, [`pdftojohn.pl`](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl). How can I use that file?

The licensing information within the file itself says:

> This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the same terms as Perl itself.

Comment: To keep this question useful in the future, I've included the relevant licensing language from the file, in case it changes locations or disappears later.

Answer (score 4):

Generally no. Usually - and unless stated expressly differently - the license applies to all files in a repository. It's good practise to state the license and copyright information in the header of all source files; but it is by no means required for copyright and license to be applicable.

In your case the file explicitly states to you what you may do under which conditions:

> This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
>   same terms as Perl itself.

So you have to abide by that. And in the case of the GPL license that means that any derivative work (thus any work which makes use of any part of it) has to be released under GPL as well.

Allow me the analogy: Just because I only steal 10% of your money doesn't mean I don't steal from you and should not be prosecuted.

Comment: I do read "the same terms as Perl itself" as an indication of "expressly different" license terms: [the licensing terms of Perl](https://dev.perl.org/licenses/) allow [either the GNU GPL or the Artisitc License 1.0](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#PerlLicense). Based on the FSF's write-up, this dual-licensing is common practice for Perl scripts, not an oversight by this script's author. I don't know what the terms of the Artistic License 1.0 are, but Wikipedia's summary indicates AL1.0 is a **not** a copyleft license (but, again, I haven't read it).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I'm new to all this licensing terms. So if I use that file from their repository what care should I take or what things should I do so that I'll not be violating their license ?

Comment: As by apsiller's comment: You can either use it, if you use the GPL license for your software. Or you follow the artistic license. Either means you have to lay open your source code and have to choose one of those licenses. Or you don't use it at all.

Comment: (I understand a brief glimps at the Artistic license that it's not OSI-approved but many conditions are open-source-like)

Comment: Yes, I'm also releasing my software under GPL, do I have to include their license in my software or can I delete it ? If yes, I have to include their license then there will be two license one belongs to them and other which I'll create. My clear question is that I have used one file from their repository what else should I include with it to obey the license.

Comment: There's a difference between license and copyright information. You should keep both, especially within that file. As both licenses require to keep attribution. You may add your own copyright additional to existing, if you modify it. You may state different copyright for different files... Why do you want to delete any license or copyright information?! Give credit whom credit is due!